# Recording audio by smartphone in DSD format i.e. PDM technology

Tags: audio-recording

Is it possible to record audio by a smartphone in DSD format i.e. PDM technology?

I guess the smartphone hardware should be able to transduce analogue sound waves into a digital bitstream in DSD format.

Are there any smartphones with such capability available to purchase?

Comment: I don't think this is on topic here - we don't do shopping recommendations. You'd need to look at the specs of each phone to see if they can store in DSD format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless a device has the capability to sample audio 2.8 million times a second (5.6 for "Hi def" version), Then No.

This requires a pretty specialized chip and/Including an extremely accurate Clock and ADC voltage/PSU to have a noticable advantage over common methods. Wikipedia "Direct Stream Digital" has a link to NativeDSD Database (by nativedsd.com), but it's play orientated, not record. I only looked at the Sony entries (since they championed the format) and no phones there. I'm sure a phone app could produce a DSD file, but it would be converted PCM for sure.